# Mailform won't submit

Tags: javascript, json, html, mailchimp, mail-form

My Mailchimp form doesn't submit when I click on the 'send' button.
It only submits when I remove the javascript, but then I will be forwarded to the mailchimp signup page: http://example.us6.list-manage.com/subscribe/post

I don't want that, because I want the Ajax functionally to keep in tact.
So if the user enters an email address and clicks on 'send' he need to get the message that he is subscribed to the newsletter without leaving the page.

Please see this [example](http://jsbin.com/ebaqam/2/edit)

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src=//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Mailchimp newsletter</title>

</head>
<body>
<form class="myform" action="http://example.us6.list-manage.com/subscribe/post" method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" name="u" value="47cdcabfbe6291e5cdaf8d06e">
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="6d2a3690d2">
  <input type="email" id="email" name="email" value=""  placeholder="your email address please" required>
  <input type="submit" value="Send" name="submit" id="submit-btn">
</form>
  <div id=message></div>
</body>
</html>
```

css:

```
#message{position:absolute;width:185px;right:0;top:30px;color:red}
```

javascript:

```
-$(document).ready(function(){$('#submit-btn').on('click',function(e){e.preventDefault();var email=$('#email').val(),validate=new RegExp(/^(("[\w-+\s]+")|([\w-+]+(?:\.[\w-+]+)*)|("[\w-+\s]+")([\w-+]+(?:\.[\w-+]+)*))(@((?:[\w-+]+\.)*\w[\w-+]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$)|(@\[?((25[0-5]\.|2[0-4][\d]\.|1[\d]{2}\.|[\d]{1,2}\.))((25[0-5]|2[0-4][\d]|1[\d]{2}|[\d]{1,2})\.){2}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][\d]|1[\d]{2}|[\d]{1,2})\]?$)/i);if(!email){
$('#message').text('Please enter your email address');return;}
if(validate.test(email)){

$.ajax({
      type:"GET",
      url: "http://example.us6.list-manage2.com/subscribe/post-json?c=?",
      data: $form.serialize(),
      dataType:'json',
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      success:function(data){$('#message').text(data['message']);if(data['success']){}}});}else{$('#message').text('Your email address seems to be invalid');}});});
```

Comment: Use the Mailchimp API. It's really comprehensive. They have a PHP class already. http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/

Comment: I know I can use the api, but I would like to keep it as simple as possible. I think that there is no need for an api and extra php requests for this job.